# How to reconized my account stripe ID for a payments attent

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to transfer money on a specific stripe connect account but when i test with one ID i have this error :
(node:8676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No such destination: 'acct_1Hlb6NQn2qN1lHlc'

Did i forget something ???

also my code :

```
const clientController = {
  createPayementIntent: async (req, res) => {
    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    /*const amount = req.body.amount;*/
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: parseFloat(req.body.amount) * 100, // pour eviter les cts
      currency: "eur",
      // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
      metadata: { integration_check: "accept_a_payment" },
      transfer_group: "ORDER_95",
    });
    await stripe.transfers.create({
      amount: parseFloat(req.body.amount) * 100,
      currency: "eur",
      destination: "acct_1Hlb6NQn2qN1lHlc",
      transfer_group: "ORDER_95",
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the account actually exists? Try:

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(
  'acct_1Hlb6NQn2qN1lHlc'
);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve

If it doesn't exist, and it should be there, check whether you are using the right Stripe platform account keys and that you are not mixing test data and production accounts.